# Shorten or simplify jQuery logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Are there any possible method to shorten the below **jQuery** code section?

I may need to repeat using the same logic for the other 8 select boxes. Many thanks.

**Code**

```js
$('#select_client').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.value;

  /* Possible to shorten this section? I have more cases like this */
  if (val == 'OTHER') {
    $('#input_client').addClass('show');
    $('#input_client').removeClass('hide');
    $('#input_client').val('');
    $('#input_client').focus();
  } else {
    $('#input_client').addClass('hide');
    $('#input_client').removeClass('show');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="select_client" name="select_client">
     <option value="1">Company A</option>
     <option value="2">Company A</option>
     <option value="3">Company A</option>
     <option value="4">Company A</option>
     <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
    </select>
<input id="input_client" type="text" class="form-control hide" placeholder="Please provide Client name" />
```

Comment: Create a function and pass it your `val` variable, this way you'll be able to call it in one line wherever you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
$('#select_client').on('change', function() {
        var val = this.value;

        /* Possible to shorten this section? I have more cases like this */
        if(val=='OTHER'){
            $('#input_client').addClass('show').removeClass('hide').val('').focus();

        } else {
            $('#input_client').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');

        }
    })
```

Comment: You can further simplify by defining your CSS in such a way that "show" (or "hide") is the *default state*, then you only need to use `show` or `hide`, not both. When you have a "boolean" state like this (ie. two options, mutually exclusive) then you should generally have it work this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select_client').on('change', function() {
    $input = $('#input_client')
      .toggleClass('show',$(this).val() ==='OTHER')
      .removeClass('hide',$(this).val() !=='OTHER');

    if($(this).val()==='OTHER'){
        $input.val('').focus();
    }
});
```

this is shorter... And you can add some condition to make it work the same function with multiple select-input couple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can chain functions to reduce redundancy for typing selector.

You can also look into `.toggleClass` if you wish to add/remove a class based on condition.

Also, instead of fetching the element again and again, you can save it in a variable and use this variable everywhere.

```js
$('#select_client').on('change', function() {
  var valid = this.value === 'OTHER';
  var $input = $('#input_client');

  $input
    .toggleClass('show', valid)
    .toggleClass('hide', !valid);
  if (valid) {
    $input
      .val('')
      .focus();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="select_client" name="select_client">
    <option value="1">Company A</option>
    <option value="2">Company A</option>
    <option value="3">Company A</option>
    <option value="4">Company A</option>
    <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
</select>
<input id="input_client" type="text" class="form-control hide" placeholder="Please provide Client name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`.toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle the display of your input according to conditionals.

Also if you are planning to have multiple select and input boxes to that, you should use **classes** instead of id.

Targeting id is not a good idea here if you have same multiple elements in your webpage.

In the below example I have used `.input_client` class as a selector.

```js
$('#select_client').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.value;

  /* Possible to shorten this section? I have more cases like this */
  if (val == 'OTHER') {
    $(this).next(".input_client").toggle("display");
    $(this).next(".input_client").val('');
    $(this).next(".input_client").focus();
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="select_client" name="select_client">
    <option value="1">Company A</option>
    <option value="2">Company A</option>
    <option value="3">Company A</option>
    <option value="4">Company A</option>
    <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
</select>
<input id="input_client" type="text" class="input_client form-control hide" placeholder="Please provide Client name" />
```